# can't insert blob file in mysql db

Tags: mysql, windows, blob, sql-insert

I have table in mysql database with 2 columns (

```
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`file` longblob).
```

When I insert file with command:

```
insert into myTable(file) value(LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\me\Desktop\myphoto.jpg"))
```

in file column shows null. Why and what should I do?
I use Windows.

Comment: Did you get errors

Comment: try `LOAD_FILE("C:/Users/me/Desktop/myphoto.jpg")`